# How do I return to the first view controller on a storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Here is the scenario:

The first scene in my storyboard is a login view. It's a UIViewController. When the user is logged in, it shows the home view which is embedded in a navigation controller. I'm adding a log out functionality which should take me back to the first scene in the storyboard which is the login view. How do I do that?

Here is an image of the storyboard showing the login view -> navigation controller -> home view
[image: Storyboard]

This is my implementation so far. In the log out action, I clear the session, and pop to root view controller. It does not work because I am still stuck on the home view since it is the root view controller of the navigation controller. However, If I restart the app, the user is logged out and I'm left with the login view.

Code:

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    // Set at beginning of storyboard
    UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.loginViewController = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];
```

Comment: [Use an unwind segue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12561735/335858).

Comment: You should add it as an answer and I will accept it. Also, it took me a while because the actions are from a UIActionSheet and the SO example all uses buttons. Let me know if you find a good way to do it all programmatically.

Comment: My comment isn't a complete answer, it's only a hint. You've got a [better answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28492711/335858) that uses the same idea.

Comment: It got me close enough though so thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use unwind segues for that.

In your LoginViewController, declare a method with this signature

`- (IBAction)unwindToLoginViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue`

Go to your HomeViewController and control drag from your logout button to the Exit button at the top of your view controller window (see screenshot below), then select the `unwindToLoginViewController` segue. That's it!

[image]

Comment: I got it to work but I'm working how to do if you want to match the segue action to a UIActionSheet button (i.e. there is no logout button or the button is generated programmatically)

Comment: Connect the controller (first icon of the three where the Exit segue icon is) to the Exit icon. Give the unwind segue a name and when you want to trigger it just use the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method.

Answer (score 2):

U can pop by using navigationController.viewControllers.Get all View Controllers among navigationController,identify it and then pop.If u have pushed the segue from LoginView to HomeView

```
if([self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]]) 
    {
      [self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] animated:YES];
    }
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: No. The login view is not embedded in a navigation controller. There is nothing left to pop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer. First you create a navigation controller. make it "is initial View Controller". After that connect login Viewcontroller as a root view controller And connect home controller with facebook button Action.

Navigation Controller -> Login Controller -> Home Controller

Your Storyboard is look like this

[image]

After that when you logout from HomeViewController then Just add this method:

```
  -(IBAction)logOut_Action:(id)sender
  {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

Its working Fine. Please implement like this and let me know if you face any problem. :)

Comment: Hey, I figured it out but not the way you did it. I don't want to the navigation controller bar appearing on the login view. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Ok, u can hide the navigation bar.  Set "Top Bar" none in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```